# web3.py is not routing properly as pancakeswap finance GUI

Tags: web3.py, python, pancakeswap, router

I have a script in python in order to execute a multicall using pancakeswap V3 router contract. Muticall sells some tokens using "swapExactTokensForTokens" from the contract. The path specified in the function is [tokenA_address, tokenB_address]. In this way, the transaction is failing because there is no liquidity directly between tokenA to tokenB.

The issue is that if you execute the sell through pancakeswap finance, is executed properly and checking the transaction the steps for the swap are for different liquidity pools.

My question is ... how can simulate this in my code. The code is the next:

```
path = [tokenB, tokenA]

swap_data1 = router_contract1.encodeABI(

fn_name="swapExactTokensForTokens",

args=[amount_in, amountOutMin, path, wallet_address]

)

data = [swap_data1]

w3.eth.set_gas_price_strategy(rpc_gas_price_strategy)

avg_gas_limit, avg_gas_used, avg_gas_estimated = (gas_limit_block(56, 1))

deadline=int(time.time()) + 600

multiCall_abi = router_contract1.encodeABI(

fn_name="multicall",

args=[deadline, data]

)

transaction = {

'from': wallet_address,

'to': router_contract1.address, # Dirección del contrato del enrutador

'value': w3.to_wei(0, 'ether'),

'gas': avg_gas_estimated,

'gasPrice': w3.eth.generate_gas_price(),

'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address),

'data': w3.toBytes(hexstr=multiCall_abi),

}

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private)

tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

BR and thanks.